# Search a text into column in a Google sheet

Tags: search, google-apps-script

I have any values in a Google sheet. 
I need search any value at the first column and where it finds it, return the value of second and third column.

Can anyone help me? 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide your current script? I think that it will help users think of your solution.

Comment: When you say any values, do you mean a particular value? If so, =vlookup should do the trick -- no script needed

Answer (score -1):

```
function test5(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange("A1:A10").getValues();
  for (var row = 0; row<data.length; row++){ 
    if (data[row]=="B") {  
      var colB = sheet.getRange(row+1,2).getValue();
      var colC = sheet.getRange(row+1,3).getValue();
      sheet.getRange(row+1,4).setValue(colB+colC);
    }
  }
}
```

You were not exactly clear on what you wanted to do with ColB and C. I added them together; result in the green cell. Depending on the size (if large) of the spreadsheet you may want to pull Col A, B and C into an array.

[image]

Comment: Some questions shouldn't get answered until OP actually asks a clear question and shows they tried something (i.e. tried to learn instead of just asking for someone to do it instead).